# I am trying to plot graphs using data from a CSV file stored in the raw folder

Tags: android

I am trying to plot graph using data from a csv file called weight_log. I am using achartengine library to plot graph. I have created an onclick button in the main activity. When i run the app it crashes ,i am not understanding what to do as neither is it showing guild build failed nor any specific errors.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chart extends MainActivity {

ArrayList<Integer> weightList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private GraphicalView mChart;
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
private XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
private XYSeries mCurrentSeries;
private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;
InputStream inputStream;
String[] data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstances) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstances);
    setContentView(R.layout.chart);
    readWeightLog();
    String data = "";

    final StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();

    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.weight_log);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    if (is != null) {
        try {
            while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sbuffer.append((data + "\n" + "\t"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void initChart() {
    mCurrentSeries = new XYSeries("Weight Log");
    mDataset.addSeries(mCurrentSeries);
    mCurrentRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mCurrentRenderer);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Time(s)");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Power(Kw/hr)");
}

private void addWeightData() {
    Integer x = 10;
    for (Integer weight : weightList) {
        mCurrentSeries.add(x += 10, weight);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    if (mChart == null) {
        initChart();
        addWeightData();
         mChart = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer, 0.3f);
        layout.addView(mChart);

    } else {
    }
}

public void readWeightLog() {
    String FILENAME = "weight_log.csv";
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    String temp;
    String a[];

    try {
        inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        byte[] reader = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        while (inputStream.read(reader) != -1) {
        }


        Scanner s = new Scanner(new String(reader));
        s.useDelimiter("\\n");
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            temp = s.next();
            a = temp.split(",");
            weightList.add(Integer.parseInt(a[2]));
        }
        s.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Chart", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Chart", e.getMessage());
            }
        }


    }
}
}
```

Logcat

```
    07-18 19:59:37.736 7482-7482/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and 
 chown /acct/uid_10060: Read-only file system

   07-18 19:59:38.348 7482-7482/com.example.muzeefa.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.muzeefa.myapplication, PID: 7482
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.muzeefa.myapplication/com.example.muzeefa.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class org.achartengine.GraphicalView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class org.achartengine.GraphicalView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.muzeefa.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:580)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.example.muzeefa.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: please share the logcat for your exception.

Comment: are you using proguard and having it minify for the build you're testing? It looks like reflection errors cause by minification

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what that is.